# for loop inside widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I use a loop inside a widget?

I want to be able to:

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan(
 text: 'Itemlist\n',
 children: <TextSpan>[

     
   for(i = 0; i< items.length; i++){

     TextSpan( text: 'item' +i +': ',),
     TextSpan( text: 'item[i].value' +i +'\n',),


     }
 
  ]
)
```

it is importaint that i could have several lines of code inside the loop.

Comment: You just need to put your for loop (put *ANY* code) inside of a function or method.  In your case, I'd create a function that returns an array of <TextSpan>[] widgets.

Comment: Try to understand the pain of a beginner. Please try to Share the solution

Comment: ok thanks I understand, thats the way its done in flutter?

Comment: Great to read @cueless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) which unfold the `Iterable<Widget>` as follows:

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Items\n',
    children: <TextSpan>[
      for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++)
        ...[
          TextSpan( text: 'Item ${i.toString()}: '),
          TextSpan( text: '${items[i]} \n',),
        ],
    ],
  ),
)
```

You can check it out in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ebdd36b5d7aab01d7f03d48e75a674bc) also.